# Use the same command in shell script, just with a prefix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a command I run to check if a certain db exists.
I want to do it locally and via ssh on a remote server.
The command is as so:

```
mysqlshow -uroot | grep -o $DB_NAME
```

My question is if I can use the same command for 2 variables,
the only difference being `ssh <remote-server>` before one?
Something along the lines of `!!` variable expansion in the CLI:

```
LOCAL_DB=mysqlshow -uroot | grep -o $DB_NAME
REMOTE_DB=ssh <remote-host> !!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this perhaps?

```
cmd="whoami"
eval $cmd
ssh remote@host $cmd
```

`eval` will run the command in the string `$cmd` locally

also, for checking tables, it's safer to ask for the table name explicitly via a query

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'yourtable';
```

and for databases:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'yourdb';
```

Comment: Yep, something like that. You think it can be reduced to maybe just 2 lines?:) And why is the query preferable?

Comment: grep can match multiple times due to a partial hit (e.g. grepping for `db1` will match `db1` and `db10`). this can be avoided by being explicit about the exact database name.

Comment: Don't use `eval` when you can simply define a shell function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in `.bashrc` something like:

```
function showrdb() {  
   ssh remote@host "$1" 
}  
export -f showrdb
```

and then source `.bashrc` and call the function like;

```
showrdb "command you want to run on remote host"
```

Or alternately you can create a shell script contains the same function(or only the `ssh` line) and call the script as

```
./scriptname "command to execute of remote host"
```

But the level of comfort for me is more in first approach.